# How to create a jumping mechanism for a small robotic car?

Tags: motor, mechanism

I have to create a jumping mechanism for a small robotic car and was thinking about using a spring mechanism to do so. However, due to dimensions (16cmx8cm) and mass constraints (below 200g) I cannot figure out what would be an optimal spring release mechanism for a small jump. My initial idea was to use a motor to wind a spring attached to a platform at the bottom of the car which would be released to make whole structure jump. Moreover, I am unsure on how to chose the right spring (equations of force and energy seem to be insufficient to find both k and x).

Comment: how many times does the robot need to jump?

Comment: how about a pneumatic ram with spring return ... open valve, gas pressure extends a piston ... close valve, spring retracts piston ... there is a youtube video about a jumping robot named sand flea

Comment: @jsotola the robot should jump when the user tells it to do so (a couple of times should be enough). I have seen the Sand Flea but it weighs about 4kg so I'm wondering if it would be possible to implement this for a robot that weighs less than 200g.